# Having subquery in each row in table is good or bad?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having on case like multiple subquery in each mysql table. I donot know wheather this concept is good or bad when large size of database table. please suggest. here I have mysql function to run subquery in select statement itself.

Here is mysql function GET_DEFAULT_VAL

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GET_DEFAULT_VAL`(
  x text
) RETURNS text
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE columnList TEXT;
  SET group_concat_max_len = 65533;
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`default_value` SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM `field_default_values` where find_in_set(`id`,x)
  INTO columnList;
  RETURN columnList;
END$$
```

Here field_default_values table

```
------------------------------------
id  |    multi_option_clm
------------------------------------

1       option1

2       option2

3       option3

4       option4
```

Here is select statement

```
select id , multi_option_clm from table1;

------------------------------------
id  |    multi_option_clm
------------------------------------

1       1,2

2       2,3,4



select id, GET_DEFAULT_VAL(`multi_option_clm`) from table1;
```

I will show result as

```
------------------------------------
id  |    multi_option_clm
------------------------------------

1       option1,option2

2       option2,option3,option4
```

will it cause any performance issue when large size database table ?

Comment: That is a complicated question that depends on the types of queries you will be running and other optimizations on the database.  As a general preference, I think that use defined functions tend to slow things down a bit compared to optimal SQL ways to do the same thing.  But, you should test the constructs you have in mind in your environment to see what happens on your data.

Comment: 1) I'd say that it might cause performance issues, especially in more complicated queries, for example, if you wanted to join with that column.

2) I think that the real problem in this design is the complexity. Since you care about performance, i assume this is not a study project, and IMO you should design your tables such an unintuitive way in business projects unless you have a very clear reasoning for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. is there any other way to get my result like above ?

Comment: @SathishBabu you can create a many-to-many relation by using an intermediate table. That would definitely make your schema more normalized.

Comment: @andreySarafanov Ya that's right. But I am creating that many to many field on the fly. Because I using this concept for custom field creation ( Form Builder). So user can create multiple field like. Thats the reason I cannot able to create third table to link that many to many column.